# Push Item to Model within a nested Repeat doesn't appear in view

Tags: angularjs

I've done a small working snippet so far to handle 'notes'. But now I do need to add Items at Runtime to my Model.

That's the JSON behind my Model:

```
[
   {
  "DocId":"SomeGuid",
  "Items":[
     {
        "Content":"SomeContent",
        "Date":"SomeDate",
        "OrderBy":0,
        "Page":1,
        "Title":"SomeTitle"
     },
     {
        "Content":"SomeContent",
        "Date":"SomeDate",
        "OrderBy":0,
        "Page":2,
        "Title":"SomeTitle"
     }
  ]
},
{
  "DocId":"SomeGuid",
  "Items":[
     {
        "Content":"SomeContent",
        "Date":"SomeDate",
        "OrderBy":0,
        "Page":1,
        "Title":"SomeTitle"
     },
     {
        "Content":"SomeContent",
        "Date":"SomeDate",
        "OrderBy":0,
        "Page":2,
        "Title":"SomeTitle"
     }
  ]
}
]
```

I now need to add a new Entry in one of those .Items.

That's my code:

```
$scope.AddNode = function (docID, page) {
            var item;
            $scope.data.forEach(function(object) {
                if (object.DocId == docID) {
                    var newNode = { Content: "", Page: page, Title: "Neue Haftnotiz", Date: "16.19.05",Id: 0,Order:0,DocId:docID };
                         $scope.data[$scope.data.indexOf(object)].Items.push(newNode);
                    return;
                }
            });
```

(btw is there any $scope.data.FindByAttribute('docId',docID)? - I couldn't find anything in this regard)

It'll push the new Item in my array, but won't update my view.
You see the results here: (Black = old, Red = pushed)
[image: Result]

My View just doesn't care if there is a new element or not - here's the template:

```
        template: '<div class="root" >\
                                       <div class="group" id="{{groupId}}-{{$index}}" ng-repeat-start="doc in ngModel" sv-root sv-part="doc.Items">\
                                            <div class="groupHeader" ><h4 style="margin-bottom:0px;" >{{doc.DocId}}</h4></div>\
                                            <div class="note panel" ng-repeat="item in doc.Items"  sv-element>\
                                                <div class="header">\
                                                    <h5>\
                                                         <a ng-click="toggleCollapsedStates($parent.$index,$index)" class="anchor" href="#{{groupBaseId}}-{{$parent.$index}}-{{$index}}">{{item.Title}} - Seite: {{item.Page}}</a>\
                                                    </h5>\
                                                    <div class="button collapsed" id="{{groupBaseId}}-{{$parent.$index}}-{{$index}}-expander"  ></div>\
                                                    <div id="{{groupBaseId}}-{{$parent.$index}}-{{$index}}-menu" class="collapse">\
                                                        <input type="button" class="button delete" ng-click="deleteNode($parent.$index,$index)"/>\
                                                        <input type="button" class="button edit" ng-click="editNode($parent.$index,$index)" id="{{groupBaseId}}-{{$parent.$index}}-{{$index}}-edit"/>\
                                                        <input type="button" class="button reference" ng-click="openReference($parent.$index,$index)"/>\
                                                    </div>\
                                                </div>\
                                                <div id="{{groupBaseId}}-{{$parent.$index}}-{{$index}}" data-parent="#{{groupId}}-{{$parent.$index}}" class="collapse">\
                                                    <textarea class="area" maxlength="255" id="{{groupBaseId}}-{{$parent.$index}}-{{$index}}-textarea" readonly>{{item.Content}}</textarea>\
                                                </div>\
                                            </div>\
                                        </div>\
                                        <div ng-repeat-end></div>\
                                    </div>',
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$scope.$apply() does the job

And the answer is too short.